# How to send data from a server to a client socket in JAVA

Tags: java, database, sockets, derby, serversocket

Sorry for the stupid question. The issue was resolved. The right question was that I wanted to send the database connections in the socket. Which actually realized that can not happen because the information between the socket is passed as messages. Again, I apologize for the stupid question. If you withdraw negative votes will be very grateful.

```
package Controller;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import View.LoginInChat;


public class ChatServer {

    private static final int PORT = 51000;
    private static String dbURL = "jdbc:derby:DesktopChatDatabase";
    public static String tableName = "APP.USERS";
    // jdbc Connection
    public static Connection conn = null;
    private static Statement stmt = null;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChatServer s = new ChatServer();
        try {
            s.run();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public void run() throws IOException{
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        createConnection();
        boolean running = true;
        while(running){
            LoginInChat.setConnectionDatabase(getConn());
            System.out.println(getConn());


            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println(client);

        }

        serverSocket.close();
    }

    public static boolean createConnection()
    {
        boolean exceptionFlag = true;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
            //Get a connection
            setConn(DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL)); 
        }
        catch (Exception except)
        {   
            except.printStackTrace();
        }

        return exceptionFlag;
    }


    public static void shutdown()
    {
        try
        {
            if (getStmt() != null)
            {
                getStmt().close();
            }

            if (getConn() != null)
            {
                DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL + ";shutdown=true");
                getConn().close();
            }           
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlExcept)
        {

        }

    }

    public static Statement getStmt() {
        return stmt;
    }

    public static void setStmt(Statement stmt) {
        ChatServer.stmt = stmt;
    }

    public static Connection getConn() {
        return conn;
    }

    public static void setConn(Connection conn) {
        ChatServer.conn = conn;
    }


}
```

Here's the client who started

```
package View;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.sql.Connection;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormAttachment;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import Controller.LoginInInterChat;

public class LoginInChat {

    protected static Shell shell;
    private Text UsernameText;
    private Text PasswordText;
    private final static String ImageLabel = "InterChatIcons" + File.separator + "ChatIconLogin.png";
    protected final static String ImageProgram = "InterChatIcons" + File.separator + "chatIcon.ico";
    protected Display display;

    private static final int PORT = 51000;
    private static final String HOST = "localhost";
    private static Socket clientSocket = null;
    public static Connection connectionDatabase;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            LoginInChat window = new LoginInChat();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public void open() {
        display = Display.getDefault();
        connectUser();
        createContents();

        System.out.println("Client Socket = " + getClientSocket());
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }

        System.out.println(getConnectionDatabase());
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     */
    protected void createContents() {
        shell = new Shell(SWT.MIN);
        shell.setSize(450, 300);
        shell.setText("InterChat");
        shell.setLayout(new FormLayout());
        shell.setImage(new Image(display, ImageProgram));

        UsernameText = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        FormData fd_UsernameText = new FormData();
        fd_UsernameText.right = new FormAttachment(0, 223);
        fd_UsernameText.top = new FormAttachment(0, 51);
        fd_UsernameText.left = new FormAttachment(0, 10);
        UsernameText.setLayoutData(fd_UsernameText);

        Label UsernameLabel = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        FormData fd_UsernameLabel = new FormData();
        fd_UsernameLabel.bottom = new FormAttachment(UsernameText, -8);
        fd_UsernameLabel.left = new FormAttachment(0, 10);
        UsernameLabel.setLayoutData(fd_UsernameLabel);
        UsernameLabel.setText("Username");

        PasswordText = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        FormData fd_PasswordText = new FormData();
        fd_PasswordText.right = new FormAttachment(0, 223);
        fd_PasswordText.top = new FormAttachment(UsernameText, 38);
        fd_PasswordText.left = new FormAttachment(0, 10);
        PasswordText.setLayoutData(fd_PasswordText);

        Label PasswordLabel = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        FormData fd_PasswordLabel = new FormData();
        fd_PasswordLabel.bottom = new FormAttachment(PasswordText, -6);
        fd_PasswordLabel.left = new FormAttachment(UsernameText, 0, SWT.LEFT);
        PasswordLabel.setLayoutData(fd_PasswordLabel);
        PasswordLabel.setText("Password");

        Button LoginButton = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        FormData fd_LoginButton = new FormData();
        fd_LoginButton.top = new FormAttachment(PasswordText, 41);
        fd_LoginButton.right = new FormAttachment(UsernameText, 0, SWT.RIGHT);
        LoginButton.setLayoutData(fd_LoginButton);
        LoginButton.setText("Login");
        LoginButton.addSelectionListener(new LoginInInterChat());

        Label LogoInterChat = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        FormData fd_LogoInterChat = new FormData();
        fd_LogoInterChat.bottom = new FormAttachment(LoginButton, 0, SWT.BOTTOM);
        fd_LogoInterChat.top = new FormAttachment(UsernameText, -41, SWT.TOP);
        fd_LogoInterChat.left = new FormAttachment(UsernameText, 35);
        fd_LogoInterChat.right = new FormAttachment(100, -2);
        LogoInterChat.setLayoutData(fd_LogoInterChat);
        LogoInterChat.setImage(new Image(display, ImageLabel));

        System.out.println("Conne is " + getConnectionDatabase());

    }

    public static Connection getConnectionDatabase() {
        return connectionDatabase;
    }

    public static void setConnectionDatabase(Connection connectionDatabase) {
        LoginInChat.connectionDatabase = connectionDatabase;
    }

    public static void connectUser()
    {
        try {
            setClientSocket(new Socket(HOST, PORT));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void setClientSocket(Socket clientSocket) {
        LoginInChat.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    public static Socket getClientSocket() {
        return clientSocket;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a "Cotto"? What is the question? (Not my down vote)

Comment: Cotto is equivalent to Class (edit my post)

Comment: The answer to the question in your title is 'same way the client sends data to the server'. If you have a null-valued variable it is because either you haven't assigned it yet or you have set it to null. Not a real question.

Comment: "When I run my client says shows that this connection is null." This seems to be the question/problem, but it would help very much if you showed us the error message.

Comment: How come the same way? When I send data to the client that the connection is null and server exist.

Comment: @Krasimir *As I already said,* if you have a null variable you haven't initialised it, etc. This is a *coding error on your part,* not a networking question at all. If you want this question answered you are going to have to ask it more intelligibly, getting rid of meaningless statements like 'what am I, but I finally this connection', and you are also going to have to get rid off all that completely irrelevant GUI code out of your post. Nobody wants to wade through all that.

Comment: The question is revised

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the Derby **client** JDBC driver but your connection URL is in derby **embedded** JDBC syntax.

Either use the Derby embedded JDBC driver, or update your connection URL syntax to be in proper client syntax format (jdbc:derby://host:port/databaseName).

[These docs](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/getstart/cgsquck70629.html) will help you understand the difference.